# Backspace strange behaviour when word selected and cursor after open parenthesis

Tags: key-bindings

I got a strange issue when I hit backspace while some text is selected and my cursor is close to an open parenthesis, example:

```
b(aaa)
```

If I select `aaa` and my cursor is on the first `a`, I would like the full `aaa` string to be removed when I hit backspace. In other words I want this:

```
b()
```

But I get that:

```
b)^?
```

where `^?` is in a different colour (may be a special character).

I suppose that the problem may come from some options or plug-in that I have like the fact that peered parenthesis are highlighted when the cursor is on it, or the command `M-<dir>` that move the cursor to the other parenthesis... I don't know.

Problem is the same whit `"` peers symbols or any peers symbols regarding the language that emacs detect. For example in C the problem is present with ``` (``"``{ ``` etc...

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Problem is the same with

```
vi(is better)
```

If I want to delete both words in the parenthesis

Comment: See the Emacs manual, node [DEL Does Not Delete](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html).

Comment: Thx but it does not resolve my problem when I toggle the variable

Comment: `M-d` will delete the word when you are on the first character (don't need to mark the word). and you probably have `paredit-mode` (or similar) on which can be disabled with `M-x paredit-mode`.

Comment: I don't have any `paredit-mode`. But thx for the `M-d` trick. However, the problem is still here when I have something like `a(word1 word2)` if i want to delete both words.

Comment: I have a similar problem when the package `autopair-mode` is enable. If this is your case, you can use `electric-pair-mode` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem come from the `autopair-mode` package.

Disable it :

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `autopair-mode`

Enable `electric-pair-mode` instead which do almost the same thing :

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `electric-pair-mode`

If all this is in init file, to clear it, remove or comment

```
(load "autopair.el") 
(require 'autopair)
(autopair-global-mode)
```

from your init file, and add

```
(electric-pair-mode t)
```

Solution provided by Lizardo Reyna in comment above